# Flask error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, flask

Attempting to fork [this flask project with bootstrap](https://github.com/esbullington/flask-bootstrap) and getting it up and running. I've followed the guide to the end on how to set it up, but I receive this error:

```
File "run.py", line 5, in <module>
    app = create_app()
  File "/home/xx/flask-bootstrap/app/__init__.py", line 21, in create_app
    config = os.path.join(app.root_path, os.environ.get('FLASK_APPLICATION_SETTINGS'))
  File "/home/xx/flask-bootstrap/venv/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 75, in join
    if b.startswith('/'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

I've installed the given dependencies with `pip install -r config/requirements.txt` yet it gives an error.

On Ubuntu 14.04, Gnome 3 DE.

`pip freeze`in the environment provides me with

```
`Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Assets==0.10
Flask-Bcrypt==0.6.2
Flask-Login==0.2.11
Flask-Script==2.0.5
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.0
Flask-WTF==0.12
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.7.3
jsmin==2.1.2
MarkupSafe==0.23
psycopg2==2.6.1
python-bcrypt==0.3.1
SQLAlchemy==1.0.6
webassets==0.10.1
Werkzeug==0.10.4
wheel==0.24.0
WTForms==2.0.2`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the error because there is no `FLASK_APPLICATION_SETTINGS` environment variable.

See the [configuration step in the readme](https://github.com/esbullington/flask-bootstrap#configuration):

> - If you're using the Makefile, be sure to set your config filename
> - Otherwise, you can either:
>
>   - pass your config file using `python manage.py -c config/yourconfig.cfg runserver` or else
>   - set an environmental variable `FLASK_APPLICATION_SETTINGS` to point to your config file
> - Check to be sure your `SECRET_KEY` config setting is indeed secret and cryptographically strong (120+ bits of entropy)
> - The Makefile command `make create_cfg` sets this `SECRET_KEY` automatically as part of the config creation

Comment: `python manage.py -c config/yourconfig.cfg runserver` also provides me with an error? What exact steps should I do, then? I don't really get what the options are and why I should pick which one? Where do I set the config filename and how?

Comment: “an error” is hardly enough information to tell you what’s wrong. And you’re probably better off asking the project’s maintainers for help here; we don’t know why they did those things, we can only guess.

Comment: I tried to paste it but I'm not allowed to post such long answers. Basically, it says `IOError: [Errno 2] Unable to load configuration file (No such file or directory): '/home/flyveren/flask-bootstrap/app/config/yourconfig.cfg'
` - again, not how to make a config and for what purpose.

Comment: Check the [quickstart section](https://github.com/esbullington/flask-bootstrap#quickstart). You need to create a config, either by using the makefile, or by creating one on your own on the basis of the examples in the config directory.

Comment: So far so good, but do I actually need to input anything in it?

Comment: Yes, that’s very likely, but again, you’re probably better off asking that the project’s maintainers, or check the source code yourself to find those answers.

Comment: I figured out how to solve it, posted as answer. Thanks for your help, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work this way:

From the virtualenv, run `make` in terminal, after this `make create_cfg`. Then `make run` starts the server and it runs as it's supposed to.